C.c.c. forcings cannot introduce diamond (Kunen Exercise IV.7.57)
Definition.

A $\diamondsuit$-sequence is a sequence $\langle A_\alpha\subset\alpha\mid \alpha\in \omega_1\rangle$ such that for all $A\subset \omega_1$, $\{ \alpha\in\omega_1\mid A\cap \alpha=A_\alpha\}$ is stationary in $\omega_1$.
A $\diamondsuit^-$-sequence is a sequence $\langle \mathcal{A}_\alpha\mid \alpha\in \omega_1\rangle$ such that each $\mathcal{A}_\alpha$ is a countable subset of $P(\alpha)$, and for all $A\subset \omega_1$, $\{ \alpha\in \omega_1\mid A\cap \alpha\in \mathcal{A}_\alpha\}$ is stationary for all $A\subset\omega_1$.

Kunen Theorem III.7.8. $\diamondsuit\leftrightarrow\diamondsuit^-$.
Exercise IV.7.57 of the book asks us to show the following:
Assume $P$ is c.c.c. in $V$ and $V^P\models \diamondsuit$. Then $V\models \diamondsuit$.
The hint is that we can use a $P$-name for a $\diamondsuit$-sequence to construct a $\diamondsuit^-$-sequence in $V$.
I've tried it but didn't succeed, would appreciate if someone could give more hints or a proof of this.

Suppose that $p \Vdash \langle \dot A_\alpha : \alpha < \omega_1 \rangle \text{ is a $\diamondsuit$-sequence}$.
Let $\mathcal{A}_\alpha = \{ A \subseteq \alpha : \exists q \leq p (q \Vdash \dot{A}_\alpha = \check{A}) \}$. Can you see why the ccc implies that this set is countable?
If $X \subseteq \omega_1$ is in $V$, then in $V[G]$, $S = \{\alpha : X \cap \alpha = \dot A_\alpha^G \}$ is stationary. In $V$, $\{ \alpha : X \cap \alpha \in \mathcal{A}_\alpha \}$ is a superset of $S$. Can you conclude from here?

Fix a name for $\lozenge$ sequence, $\dot A_\alpha$. For each $\alpha<\omega$ we define $\mathcal A_\alpha=\{X\subseteq\alpha\mid\exists p, p\Vdash\dot A_\alpha=\check X\}$. Namely, we look at all the possible ground model candidates for $\dot A_\alpha$. Since $P$ is a c.c.c. forcing, each $\cal A_\alpha$ is countable.
Suppose that $A\subseteq\omega_1$, then $1\Vdash\dot S=\{\alpha<\omega\mid\check A\cap\check\alpha=\dot A_\alpha\}$ is a stationary set. Note that $A\cap\alpha$ is in $V$, so if $p\Vdash\check\alpha\in\dot S$, then $A\cap\alpha\in\cal A_\alpha$.
Finally, since $P$ is a c.c.c. forcing, there is a stationary set $T\in V$ such that $1\Vdash\check T\subseteq\dot S$, so the $\cal A_\alpha$ form a $\lozenge^-$ sequence.
